# How to read and map an incoming Json String from ajax to C# asp.ne MVC Controller

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

Ajax:

```
 $.ajax({
        async: true,
        type: 'Post',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        traditional: true,
        processData: false,
        data: JSON.stringify(myData),
        url: '/Shopping/Order',
        success: function (response) {
            console.log("response.sussces: " + response.success);
            console.log("response.message: " + response.message);
            console.log("response.data: " + response.data);
        },
        error: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
```

I'm trying to iterate ItemList, Which comes in json format as

```
{
 "ItemList": [
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Item 3",
    "desc": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text",
    "price": 361.05,
    "image": "../images/no_image.png",
    "count": 1
  },
  {
    ...
  },
  ...
 ]
}
```

my Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Order([FromBody] ItemList list)
    {

        var response = new
        {
            Success = true,
            Message = "Item Added Succesfully",
            Data = list.Items.Count() // result: System.ArgumentNullException: value can't be null
        };

        var jsonResult = Json(response);

        return jsonResult;
    }
```

when i assign list.ToString() to Data.
Data value become ( ShowCase.Controllers.ItemList ).

On the other hand, i receive the incoming data from ajax when i declare the parameter as an Object type.

Controller after Modification:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Order([FromBody] Object list)
    {


        var response = new
        {
            Success = true,
            Message = "Item Added Succesfully",
            Data = list.ToString()
        };

        var jsonResult = Json(response);

        return jsonResult;
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Edited: Item & ItemList Classes

```
    public class Item
    {
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public string Name { get; set; }
      public string Desc { get; set; }
      public double Price { get; set; }
      public string Image { get; set; }
      public int Count { get; set; }
    }

    public class ItemList
    {
      public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
    }
```

Json string list: `var myData = {ItemList: JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('shoppingCart'))};`

to produce this:

"ItemList": [
{
"id": 3,
"name": "Item 3",
"desc": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text",
"price": 361.05,
"image": "../images/no_image.png",
"count": 1
},
{
...
},
...
]
}

Comment: Should your Json have `{` before the property `ItemList` which have mentioned in *to produce this:*

Comment: Thanks for the note, i didn't noticed that curly brackets. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ItemList` is a property of your JSON object. So create a new class as shown below and it should have the `ItemList` as property.

```
public class OrderRequest
{
    public ItemList ItemList {get; set; }
}
```

And change the signature of action to

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Order([FromBody]OrderRequest orderRequest)
```

and to access the count

```
Data = orderRequest.ItemList.Items.Count()
```

Comment: same issue, i got "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: Can you post the class structure of `ItemList` in your question?

Comment: Sorry i forgot to posted along with the question, I just edited.